# PowerShell Script/Refresh

Tags: powershell

I have a script that installs software and logs what is happening. At the end of the install I use a command to check if the software is installed via the registry. Here is part of the script:

```
#Install Adobre Reader
Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Installing Adobe Reader"
$AdobeInstaller = "\\server\AcroRead.msi"
$AdobeArgs = 'TRANSFORMS="\\server\AcroRead.mst" /qn /norestart'  

Start-Process $AdobeInstaller $AdobeArgs -Wait

#Check Adobe Reader Install
$InstalledProgs2 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
                   Select-Object DisplayName
$CheckProg2 = $InstalledProgs -like "*Adobe Acrobat Reader DC*"
if ( $CheckProg2 ) {
    Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Adober Reader install finished successfully"
} else {
    Write-Verbose "$(Get-Date): Adobe Reader install failed"
}
```

The script waits for the installer to finish, as it should, but then always reports as "Adobe Reader install failed" even though it is installed. If I run "check" part of the script after the initial script has finished it works as it should. It appears to me that PowerShell caches the current registry at the start of PowerShell and does not see the new install. Is there a command to refresh this or am I thinking incorrectly?

Comment: Typo in `$CheckProg2 = $InstalledProgs -like "*Adobe Acrobat Reader DC*"`. You should check `$InstalledProgs2`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! However that does not seem to change the results. I have three other pieces of software installed/checked the same way in the same script, hence the 2 addition, and the others are correct and report incorrectly.

Comment: Alright, I have added a start-sleep command to wait 5 seconds after install and that seems to have fixed my issue.